# Communicate with foreground service android

Tags: android, service, bind, foreground, aidl

First question here, but I've been around for a while.

**What do I have:**

I'm building an Android app which plays audio streams and online playlists. Everything is working fine now, but I'm having issues in communicating with my service.

The music is playing in a Service, started with startForeground, so it doesn't gets killed.

I need to communicate from my activity with the service, for getting the track name, image, and a couple of things more.

**Whats my issue:**

I think I need to start my service with bindService (instead of my current startService) so the activity can talk to it.

However, when I do that, my service gets killed after closing the Activity.

How can I get both? Binding and foreground service?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried making a notification for your service? I think that should help stop it getting killed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. `bindService` will not start a service . It will just bind to the `Service` with a `service connection`, so that you will have the `instance` of the service to access/control it.

As per your requirement I hope you will have the instance of `MediaPlayer` in service . You can also start the service from `Activity` and then `bind` it. If the `service` is already running `onStartCommand()` will be called, and you can check if `MediaPlayer` instance is not null then simply return `START_STICKY`.

Change you `Activity` like this..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    CustomService customService = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // start the service, even if already running no problem.
        startService(new Intent(this, CustomService.class));
        // bind to the service.
        bindService(new Intent(this,
          CustomService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            customService = ((CustomService.LocalBinder) iBinder).getInstance();
            // now you have the instance of service.
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            customService = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (customService != null) {
            // Detach the service connection.
            unbindService(mConnection);
        }
    }
}
```

I have similar application with `MediaPlayer` `service`. let me know if this approach doesn't help you.

Comment: In my situation if I unbind on my service. The service gets killed. Because the only activity that has bound to it has been closed/got off the view. This is highly documented. I am doing a downloader system for my app. But it kills the service. When the downloader is done, I have stopSelf called somewhere within the service so my Service is not at all running forever. Any ideas?

Comment: the OP asked about `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()`, this answer just deals with `startService()` and doesn't deal with the AIDL, either.

Comment: Note that bindService() does create the service, without one having to call startService().  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 13):

Quoting [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> A bound service is destroyed once all clients unbind, unless the service was also started

And about the difference between *started* and *bound* just take a look to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

So, you have to create the Service using [`startService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) and then `bindService`, like @Libin does in his/her example. Then, the service will run until you use [`stopService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) or [`stopSelf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) or until Android decides that it needs resources and kills you.

Comment: the problem is that a bound/started service gets restarted once the activity is destroyed, for a music player that means that the music restarts halfway

Comment: Are you running it [in foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services?hl=en#Foreground)?

Comment: it should be run as foreground, but not as a bound/started service