# how can I make a Foreground Service to work even if I close the app in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, service, background-process

I have an Android app developed in Kotlin and it has a button to share a file. If I close the app before this process is completed, the file isn't shared and when I re-open the app, I have to start all the process again: select the file, click the button, and wait.
I want it to continue working even if I close the app, so I added this class to my project:

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
import android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

class ForegroundService : Service() {
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundService Kotlin"

    companion object {

        fun startService(context: Context, message: String) {
            val startIntent = Intent(context, 
ForegroundService::class.java)
            startIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", message)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startIntent)
        }

        fun stopService(context: Context) {
            val stopIntent = Intent(context, ForegroundService::class.java)
            context.stopService(stopIntent)
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        //do heavy work on a background thread
        val input = intent?.getStringExtra("inputExtra")
        createNotificationChannel()
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        }
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service Kotlin Example")
            .setContentText(input)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
        //stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager!!.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }
}
```

and this code into my MainActivy.kt:

```
buttonStart.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        ForegroundService.startService(requireActivity(), "Foreground Service is running...")
    })

    buttonStop.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        ForegroundService.stopService(requireActivity())
    })
```

When I run the app in an emulated phone on Android Studio (a Pixel 6 Pro API 30), I see there is a notification but when I run it on my phone, a Samsung Galaxy, I don't see any notification.

In both cases, if I press the button "Start Service", the button "Share file" and I close the app, the app doesn't continue working on the background. It resumes when I re-open it. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something called a Foreground Service, which will keep running even if the app terminates; you need to check [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services) to convert your Service into a foreground service.

You need to make a permission in your manifest like that:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and then you need to call it like that:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(...) // Build the intent for the service
applicationContext.startForegroundService(intent)
```

and if you need to communicate with this service, you need to to create service Connection, check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017767/communicate-with-foreground-service-android).

Hope this help!

Comment: thank you! I tried but I basically have the same issue. I updated my question. Could you take a look, please?

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to make use of another permission called REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS which shall produce a prompt like "Always run in Background" to user

Comment: thank you! I tried it and it looks like I don't need to include also the FOREGROUND_SERVICE, just adding the REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS  permission in the Manifest makes the app work in the background, without the need to call it in the code. is that right?

Comment: You need Foreground service to display notifications, the request_ignore_battery_optimization was  to make sure the os doesnt kill the app during idle or doze mode which i suspected was the problem you were facing, so you need it

Comment: Also make sure you dont violate google policies while using this permission,
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#:~:text=Note%3A%20Google%20Play%20policies%20prohibit,list%20by%20calling%20isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations()%20.

Comment: that link describes policies for messaging apps. my app doesn't need any internet connection, it is a video processor, so I guess the policies apply.